# Je me demande s’il était / est beau

Tags: conjugaison

Bonjour,

A entre dans une chambre et voit B qui lit un livre. Elle pense :

> Pour la première fois, je me demande s’il **était** beau.
>
> Pour la première fois, je me demande s’il **est** beau.

Les deux phrases sont correctes, n'est-ce pas ? La première serait une hypothèse alors que la deuxième un constat.

Answer (score 1):

La première phrase s'interroge sur le passé de B :

> Est-ce qu'il était beau avant ?

La deuxième s'interroge sur son apparence actuelle :

> Est-ce qu'il est beau maintenant ?

Une hypothèse se formulerait plutôt comme ceci :

> Ne serait-il pas beau ?

> Et s'il était beau ?

Et un constat comme cela :

> Je constate/découvre/observe/me rend compte qu'il est beau.

Comment: Merci, jlliagre. Je pensais que l'on pouvait omettre "Et" dans "Et s'il était beau ?" et que la phrase resterait toujours une hypothèse.

Comment: J'ai mis un *et* pour que la phrase soit complète. Sans ce *et*, il faudrait une deuxième proposition, par exemple : *S'il était beau, pourrait-il avoir le rôle ?*

Comment: OK, merci beaucoup !

Comment: C'était pas immédiatement acquis pour moi qu'on ne parlait pas du livre. En me demandant pourquoi je me suis rendu compte que c'est parce que j'aurais utilisé le verbe _trouver_ (si je le trouvais beau).